# Rails: Url Parameter overriding form post parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am posting a form in rails. my car_id parameter is being overriden by the url parameter.

How do I change this behavior?

My url looks like

http://localhost:3000/form?car_id=nissan

However, my form is..

```
       <%= form_with mycontroller_path, method: :post do |f| %>

<% Car.all.each do |car| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= radio_button_tag "car_id", car.id, @car.id == car.id,  class: "selected-car"%></td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <%= label_tag "car_id_#{car.id}" do %>
        <span data-label="Car" class="text-left col-md-6" >
          <%= car.name %>
        </span>
        <span data-label="Price" class="text-left col-md-6" >
          <%= car.formatted_amount %>
        </span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td data-label="">
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

  ...    
 <% end %>
```

My form parameter is always override by the URL parameter, how do I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, `radio_button_tag "car_id"` should be `radio_button_tag "car_id_#{car.id}",` to make it different per each car.

In the controller, if you have different params with the same name in the URL and in the request body, you can differentiate them with `request.POST` for the ones coming from the form and `request.GET` for the ones coming from the url.

Comment: Different car_id means that it submits different keys and you can select multiple radios. This acts more like checkbox. I need a radio

Comment: It's coming from a post, request.POST does give correct parameter, but request.GET returns nil, since it's a post. Why does params, give the wrong value?